# retrieve data from servlet using jquery

Tags: jquery, servlets

I want to use a servlet to return data to an html page using jscript and jquery get. It does not work and  I don’t see why. I’m using tomcat 7.056, servlet-api-2.5 and jquery-1.11.1.min.js

The problem is in the following linecode:

```
 $.get('htp://.../ServletTeste2', function(responseText) {
```

Servlet Code

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletTeste2 extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String text = "example text";
    response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    response.getWriter().write(text);       
  }
}
```

Html code

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>SO question 4112686</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#somebutton').click(function() {
        $('#somediv').text("hello....");
        //document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/ServletTeste2";

        $.get('http://localhost:8080/ServletTeste2', function(responseText) {
          $('#somediv').text("hello....");
          $('#somediv').text(responseText);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="somebutton">press here</button>
  <div id="somediv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Mapping

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletTeste2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ServletTeste2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletTeste2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletTeste2/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Notice that if I remove // from

```
//document.location.href = "http:..../ServletTeste2";
```

the servlet work, i.e. I have a new page on screen with “example text" on screen.

The problem is that

```
$.get('http://.../ServletTeste2',
```

returns false but

```
document.location.href = "http://.../ServletTeste2";
```

works.

Comment: is this a cross domain request? Inspect the request itself in browser console network tab for more clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Servlets but the problem seems to be related (as NomeshDeSilva pointed out) to a cross-domain AJAX problem.

Check your console to check if you have an error like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If so, then this means you need to give permission on the server indicating that cross domain requests are accepted.

Since, in this case, you control the code of the servlet just try adding the following line into the servlet code:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

**Important note**: the wildcard allows for any domain to send requests to your host. After checking that this fixes the problem, it's recommended that you replace the "*" with the specific domain from which you'll be sending your requests.

Comment: it worked .. you guys are geniuses .. thanks NomeshDeSilva and A Lopes